# How to ship a C++ - application with a single boost library

Tags: c++, boost

at first sorry if the question was asked before, but i found nothing by searching.

At second:

- I'm using Kubuntu 12.04,
- gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3,
- boost v1.48.0

As the title says, I have an application which uses the *boost / program options* Library.

Now I want to ship the source code of the application to my teacher, but he has not installed Boost. I am searching for a way to extract the corresponding source files from the whole boost library to ship only that files, that are really needed.

What I now want is a folder containing the headers and cpp files and a simple `make` by my teacher on his machine does the job.

But I don't know how to get that files.

- I've found `bcp` but I don't know what to do with the output. There are .hpp and .cpp files but when I try to compile I get errors over errors...
- Then I've seen the `bootstrap.sh` script in the boost folder and I called it with `bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=program_options`. That constructed a binary library and header files for **every** library.

Now I used the `libboost_program_options.a` from the second step and the header files from the first step *together*:

I put the path to the headers with `-I path_to_header` on the include-path and linked statically against `libboost_program_options.a`.

That even comiled and ran perfectly, but only on my machine and not on the machine of a friend, who is using Fedora 17 with gcc 4.7.x.

Is there any working and easy way like *"put that header files and that cpp files in a folder and add the path to the cpp files to the list in your Makefile and then run make and HEY there you have the program"*?

Thanks

Comment: The problem with shipping it with specific Boost code is that there will be a lot of dependencies to sort out so you'll end up shipping a lot of code anyway. Boost source code heavily depends upon itself.

Comment: The static library approach was the proper one. What didn't work about it on your friend's machine? You didn't say. Let's focus on debugging that.

Comment: Use the [bcp](http://www.boost.org/tools/bcp) tool to extract the subset you want. But be aware that this is not going to be a small set of files.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: If you can wait until tomorrow, I can give you the log. I don't see him earlier. But I remember, that the problem was a linker problem about not available data types. I've searched with Google but didn't find any issues with Boost and gcc 4.7.x affecting me...

Comment: @Wolfe: Stack Overflow is asynchronous -- I can wait until tomorrow precisely as much as I can not wait until tomorrow, and more than I can answer this now... :) It's more about _you_ waiting until tomorrow, but I do think you're gonna have to. Otherwise we're all just guessing...

Comment: That's one of those situations where you really want a VM to actually test the deployment - makes it much easier to debug such things.

Comment: @Praetorian: The `bcp` extracts me headers and source files. When I add them to my project and try to compile I get a lot of errors, to be precisely more errors, than I can write in this box, so I give you the first ones:

In file included from src/boost/libs/detail/utf8_codecvt_facet.cpp:13:0:
/usr/include/boost/detail/utf8_codecvt_facet.hpp:104:1: Fehler: »BOOST_UTF8_BEGIN_NAMESPACE« bezeichnet keinen Typ
/usr/include/boost/detail/utf8_codecvt_facet.hpp:188:1: Fehler: »BOOST_UTF8_END_NAMESPACE« bezeichnet keinen Typ

Comment: @Praetorian: The other errors also complain, that types are not declared and methods are not found. They come all from that single file. Maybe there's a dependency which was not resolved by `bcp`?!

Comment: GYP maybe help.
GYP: http://code.google.com/p/gyp

Comment: Now I've done, what Voo said: I set up a virtual machine and installed Fedora 17. In Kubuntu I build the project in the way described above and linked it against the static library. It worked without any problems. However in Fedora if I call make, I get a lot of errors like this: `.text._ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_17bad_function_callEED1Ev[_ZN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_17bad_function_callEED1Ev]' of boost/lib/libboost_program_options.a(cmdline.o): defined in discarded section ... collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know, if this is the *answer*, you want to hear from me, but now my teacher installed the boost library on his computer, after he heard about these issues...

Now I'm able to link the files with the `-lboost_program_options` option and it works on my machine, on my friend's one and (probably the most important) on my teachers one...

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create an amalgamation of your source code? For each source file you can run

```
gcc -E source.cpp
```

to obtain the preprocessor output. Then you can separate the header part from your actual source code, just for clarity. Includes are reduced to one file only.

Comment: I never heard about that option... I will have a look in the documentation and keep it in mind :). However, the issue was _solved_ by my teacher, who installed boost...

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [-M (or -MM)](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-M-926) command line option which should get you all the files a particular source file depends on.